# SQL Design Patterns

Tags: sql, design-patterns, database-design

Is there such a thing as Design Patterns in SQL ???

Comment: Does this refer to DB design or patterns for queries?

Comment: If you're talking about how to write a select statement for a certain scenario then I totally hear you on this question.

Comment: [Joe Celko's SQL Programming Style](http://www.amazon.com/Celkos-Programming-Kaufmann-Management-Systems/dp/0120887975/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1335816555&sr=1-1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to look at [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) which is some sort of general Design Pattern in SQL.

Comment: There is also a SQL 'anti-pattern' book coming soon.

http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns

Comment: And I've looked at two chapters of said book, and at this point, it's got some magnificent errors in it. The following from the book is supposed to fetch a random row from a table in Oracle, and it's got two showstopper errors in it: 

$offset = $pdo->query("SELECT dbms_random.value(1, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bugs) AS offset FROM dual)")->fetch(); $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Bugs WHERE ROWNUM = :offset" ); $stmt->execute( $offset ); $rand_bug = $stmt->fetch();

Comment: SQL design pattern is different from Database Design Pattern. SQL design pattern is about programming, not database design.

Answer (score 12):

A design pattern is simply a recognised way of solving a problem that works in different specific circumstances. Do such things exist in SQL? Of course - for example implementing many to many relationships between two tables using a third table.

Answer (score 10):

Yes.  :)

[SQL Design Patterns: Expert Guide to SQL Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0977671542)

(Not even sure if this is a recommended book.. just illustrating that "proper design" exists).

Comment: I live in a universe of "improper design" in both the host side(.NET) and database side(MS SQL SERVER). I am just wondering if I will ever get to work in an evironement where fellow programmers DON'T take pride in shunning books and "GETTING THE JOB DONE".

Comment: You and me both my man.  We are constantly balancing results vs. good OO code. Seems like one or the other always has to suffer...

Comment: This book costs as much as a SQL Server License